# Terraform: passing var to function

Tags: terraform

I am trying to dynamically create subnets in a `tf` file, using the `cidrsubnet` function and passing to it the cidr as variable.

However the following

```
  cidr_block              = "${cidrsubnet(${var.vpc_cidr}, 8, count.index + 1)}"
```

yields this error:

> **Error**: Invalid expression
>
> on modules/subnets/main.tf line 9, in resource "aws_subnet"
>
> "env_vpc_sn":    9:   cidr_block              =
>   "${cidrsubnet(${var.vpc_cidr}, 8, count.index + 1)}"
>
> Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression
>   token.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The "invalid expression token" is `${` before `var.vpc_cidr`. Just replace the right hand side with this: `"${cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, count.index + 1)}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you opened the interpolation syntax, you no longer have to specify it for each interpolation.

In other words, instead of:

```
${cidrsubnet(${var.vpc_cidr}, 8, count.index + 1)}
```

specify:

```
${cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, count.index + 1)}
```